# Full reindex process is already running even after rebooting SQL

Tags: reindex, enterprise-1.13

I have tried this solution:

[Full reindex process is already running](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14679/full-reindex-process-is-already-running)

But that does not work, I still get the same error. The error started because the client server was full.

I have cleared space on the server and removed the lock files. I even tried rebooting the SQL server. (No help)

I cleared my var/ directory of everything.

I restarted Apache

I restarted MySQL (It's on a separate box)

I have tried via command line and Magerun

Here is some output

```
magerun index:reindex catalog_product_attribute


  Reindex  


Full reindex process is already running.
```

I have tried running the command as root as well

```
 php indexer.php reindexall
Full reindex process is already running.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a *correctly* set up Magento environment.  My guess is that your {docRoot}/var directory is writable by your server user, but not by your CLI user.  Because of that Magento will switch to using /tmp/magento for var.  So the CLI may be trying to write to /tmp/magento/var/locks/reindex.lock.  Try su-ing to the web user and see if it works

The final solution ended being the cron running at root which was locking the lock files.

Comment: I ran the command as the web user. I can try changing the folder to 777?

Comment: Kevin, that did not help

Comment: chmod -R ?  If that doesn't work you will need to debug Mage_Index_Model_Lock::_setLockFile() (Enterprise_Index_Model_Observer::lockFullReindexProcess() uses file locks exclusively, which is where the exception is thrown) to see where the lock file exists.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue, Magento has already given us one patch, I will keep you posted